# remove hadoop info streaming.PipeMapRed and others

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run hadoop, I get many info massages. So I want to remove unuseful, such as INFO streaming.PipeMapRed, INFO mapred.MapTask etc. And retain the most important - INFO mapreduce.Job. 
So how to do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDiWu.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Interface in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` called `Reporter` which provides report progress and update counters, status information etc. If you have access to the code, You can eliminate `INFO` messages and report imporant ones with `setStatus` method.